# Resolve MySQL error when changing engine from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, mysql-error-1025

My database experienced some corruption last week, and the technicians from the web hosting company changed all my tables to MyISAM and performed repair on those tables.

However, my application requires InnoDB tables. I've tried the method mentioned in [this website](http://rackerhacker.com/2007/10/03/convert-myisam-tables-to-innodb/) However, I get this message

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './user_db/#sql-689d_6e416' to './user_db/api_role' (errno: 121)
```

What should I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [article here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/22/mysqls-error-1025-explained/) which explains the error code you're seeing.